# Problems running MPI (OpenMPI) app on Linux on ARM

Tags: linux, arm, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/5759/#install-openmpi) for building and running an MPI application on an ARM based Ubuntu 11.10 system.

When installing open-mpi environment on my PC machine, the sample program runs well. However, trying the same on the ARM machine, the terminal hangs up and I need to kill the MPI process from a second terminal in order to release it.

The MPI packages I installed using apt-get, on both machines, were `mpi-default-dev` and `mpi-default-bin`, so I assume that the packages are as updated as they can be.

The first sample program in the tutorial makes every process prints a "hello" message with some info. On the PC I get messages from all 8 processes (although running on a single core) and then the program ends. On the ARM, I get no output at all. The program is just stuck immediately after launch.

**Any idea on what's wrong? I am not sure even where to start to debug this?**

**Update:** I tried removing the OpenMPI package and install the alternative MPICH2 package - but the result is just the same.

Comment: Try running your program on one process only `mpiexec -n 1` or whatever variation thereof you use.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - thanks, already tried that.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - actually, following the tutorial, I used `mpirun -np1 ...`. Should this make a difference?

Comment: I wouldn't expect so.  I use `mpiexec` because it is standard across MPI implementations (or ought to be). There used to be variation in the capabilities and syntax of `mpirun` on the different MPI implementations but what you have written looks OK to me.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - gave it a try. mpiexec does not work either.

Comment: Interesting quote form the manpage: `Note: mpirun, mpiexec, and orterun are all synonyms for each other.  Using any of the names will produce the same behavior.`

Comment: `orterun` is the ORTE (Open MPI Runtime Environment) launcher. ORTE is one of the basic frameworks that Open MPI is built on.

Comment: @HristoIliev - thenks. Looking at the bin/ directory one can see that mpirun and mpiexec are symlinks to oprterun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 did not ship with a functional Open MPI implementation for ARM (although it may have shipped with a nonfunctional one). Ubuntu 12.04 did.

I would recommend building your own Open MPI from source - available at http://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.6/, unless you can update to a more recent version of Ubuntu.

Alternatively, you could rebuild the 11.10 package using the fixes pointed out in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openmpi/+bug/949044.

Comment: Thanks, this may explain why the pre-built packages did not work. Yesterday I ended up building the package from the sources downloaded form the OpenMPI website. It did require some thorough cleaning of the system from remains of the old packages but once done, it now runs the hello-world example on a single computer.